# How to use puppeteer with NordVPN?

Tags: puppeteer, vpn

Any existing sample on how to use puppeteer with nordVpn ?

I tried that:

```
page = await browser.newPage();
await useProxy(page, `socks5://login:password}@fr806.nordvpn.com:1080`);
```

I also tried:

```
'--proxy-server=socks5://login:password@fr806.nordvpn.com:1080'
```

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

This script works, you need to change the user/pass to yours... these are not your Nord user/pass... you need to get the service/api ones from in your account settings. Change the server to whatever one you need to use.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// Screengrab generator
// outputs a JSON object with a base64 encoded image of the screengrab
// eg;


const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let conf          = new Object();

conf.url      = "https://www.telegraph.co.uk";

// VPN
conf.vpnUser   = conf.vpnUSer   || 'USERNAME';
conf.vpnPass   = conf.vpnPass   || 'PASSWORD';
conf.vpnServer = conf.vpnServer || "https://uk1785.nordvpn.com:89";



(async() => {


    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: true,
            args: [
                    '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
                    '--proxy-server='+conf.vpnServer
            ]
    });

    try {
      const page = await browser.newPage();

      await page.authenticate({
        username: conf.vpnUser,
        password: conf.vpnPass,
      });

      await page.goto(conf.url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });


    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } finally {
        await browser.close();
    }


})();
```

Comment: This doesn't work, TIMEOUT, I'd really like to understand how to use it